# Is there any support for microtonality and temperaments in (or beyond) the MIDI specification?

Tags: tuning, midi, temperament, microtonality

The number of tones (or notes) per 8ve is just one of many potentially customisable aspects of any instrument. Standard midi, however, is pretty much clamped to western 12-tone equal temperament. Escaping it's confines implies external mapping devices or software, but these deal with effects rather than causes.

The General MIDI Level 2 spec would seem to have been around since 1999. As a latecomer to all this, has any **alternative** emerged in the meantime that allows native, dedicated mappings to NON-12 tone notes/8ve and OTHER than equal temperaments?

I'm specifically NOT looking for [hardware or software workarounds](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14481/are-there-any-midi-extensions-that-allow-quarter-tones) but for a more worldly view in the form of improved standards.

I imagine something along the lines of a tones- (or notes-) per-8ve indexing system, whereby the enharmonic notes in each octave are a multiple of the lowest octave's note indexes, alternative temperaments being expressed by mappings to their parallel cent, frequency or similar values. Much the same as midi, but with flexible indexing...

Glad for any info.

Answer (score 8):

The [MIDI Tuning Standard](http://www.midi.org/techspecs/midituning.php) allows for arbitrary remapping of all 128 note values. It was ratified in 1992, and can be implemented by both GM and GM2 devices. (Very few do, however.)

There are also Scale/Octave Tuning messages, which allow slight adjustments to the 12 tones in an octave. Only these are required by GM2.

Comment: Midi, with a 127 bit indexing limit, seems likely to fall apart for real-world, long-necked and/or higher-order microtonal  (26, 31, 43, 50, 53 TET) world music instruments and scales, yet these are my area of interest.

Comment: Note that MTS isn't supported by very many software synths.

Comment: It’s also not widely supported in hardware synths

Answer (score 4):

There's scattered support for other 12-tone temperaments, but MIDI just isn't going to be able to work with tuning systems with more notes.  It's an issue of the amount of information that a MIDI message can encode--the existing standard is for a 7-bit (128-value) note number, which is enough to encode over 10 octaves of 12-tone, but only 5 octaves of quarter tones, which isn't going to cut it.  You could design a new format based on MIDI that makes this kind of extension, but it won't be backwards-compatible with MIDI 1.0, and once we've given that up, we might as well move on entirely.

Comment: Agree entirely. My impulse is to work with a simple n-tone-per-octave indexing system, mapping to midi where it makes sense (more or less those systems representable using the graphical elements of standard music notation) but otherwise waiting until the world catches up. Mappings are a palliative, standards the cure. :-)

Comment: The MIDI Tuning Standard allows sending arbitrary frequencies for each note, so I don't think it matters how many  MIDI notes there are.

Answer (score 3):

I know that you state that you are not looking for "workarounds", but I should point this out.

There is indeed ***not*** a properly-supported means of doing microtonality within the MIDI specification itself. However, there is an extremely well-established and widely-accepted and implemented system for microtonality with synthesizers and virtual instruments called **Scala**, and it's easy to use and its microtonal tuning tables are portable and reproducible across many pieces of music software and hardware. **Scala** supports a myriad of historical tunings and temperaments, as well as avant-garde experimental tunings and any arbitrary tunings you might devise yourself.

Don't wait for the MIDI standard to be upgraded or extended for microtonal scales; people who want and need them have been content to use the **Scala** system to achieve this instead.

You can read about it at the [Scala website](http://www.huygens-fokker.org/scala/).

Here is the [Wikipedia article on Scala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_(software)).

There are many commercial and freeware software virtual instruments that support Scala directly. Examples include [Native Instruments](http://www.native-instruments.com/en/), the [Garritan Personal Orchestra](http://www.garritan.com/UserManuals/CFXConcertGrand/Content/historical_tuning_and_stretch_tuning.htm), and [Pianoteq](https://www.pianoteq.com/pianoteq5). These products come with libraries of Scala historical temperaments and ethnomusicological tuning tables already available as presets. You don't need to know how to program your own Scala tuning tables to get started, but the Scala system has free software for building your own tunings if you are so inclined, and you can import your own library of Scala tunings into these virtual instruments.

Beyond that, the Scala system includes software that can export Scala tunings (simpler ones of no more than 12 pitches per octave at least) into MIDI specification-format data that can be uploaded into many hardware synths that  support the MIDI tuning spec. There is a long list of hardware synths going back to the Yamaha DX7 that support the MIDI tuning spec and will work with the Scala software.

So please don't discount "workarounds"; the Scala system can do what you want.

[image]

*The [Pianoteq](https://www.pianoteq.com) virtual instrument digital piano comes with many Scala microtonal tuning tables, or you can import your own Scala files from disk.*

[image]

Comment: Scala is anchored to a specific OS. Have you examples of successful Scala datafile usage in a cloud/browser context? If flexible and proven, there would be a strong argument for their integration (in the form of load and handling functions) into data visualization libraries such as d3.js, allowing them to be exploited with much the same ease as -say- the widely used json or csv formats.

Comment: Scala's datafiles have indeed been integrated into a [javascript library](https://github.com/kchapelier/Aural.js). More recently, the same developer seems to have been taking a crack at a [public API](https://github.com/kchapelier/aural-scala). Looks promising.

Comment: The Scala creation software is available for Windows, Linux and Mac OS X. http://www.huygens-fokker.org/scala/downloads.html. However most people who use Scala files just rely on the presets available with the particular virtual instrument. They never go near the creation software.

Comment: Here's a tip. The freeware sforzando sample player by Plogue, a standalone virtual instrument and plugin in all common formats for Windows and Mac OS X, supports playback using Scala tables. http://www.plogue.com/products/sforzando/

Comment: @user2165086 those `.scl` files use a very simple text-based format. You can create them with any text editor or scripting language, don't need Scala or any specific library. For instance, [here's 31-edo](https://gist.github.com/leftaroundabout/046cc085499b9bc87d7b).

Comment: Regardless of that: I'd say that workarounds like `.scl` (though they do work) remain ugly hacks, and we shouldn't really content ourselves with them. It's a disaster that 7-bit MIDI is still around after being technically out of date for two decades; let's try to at least encourage developers to think of some better replacement rather than focusing on the adaption MIDI for applications it wasn't originally meant to do – it's bad enough at the stuff it _was_ meant for!

Comment: Agreed. Regarding `.scl` files: a typical use case: map all 17 or 19 tone just intoned Turkish bağlamas to each of their regional scale variations. Seen in this context, `.scl` files suffer from at least five weaknesses: 1) reliable identification by end users of content **from their naming**, 2) some tone-per-8ve to scale mappings seem likely to need consensus approval by ethnic musicians, 3) content needs to be more rigorously documented to take account of use across possibly multiple regions, 4) lack of a convenient, standard format (json or other) and 5) a lack of proven, public APIs.

Answer (score 1):

*(February 7th, 2019)* I believe at NAMM recently, MIDI 2.0 was announced. It will be much more powerful, allowing (though current MIDI is just fine and the new one will be backwards compatible) more possibilities and features than are currently necessary. Perhaps microtonal music will be supported more fully in this new system. Adam Neely explains this new MIDI much better than I can.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Scala format seems to be taking over. Developers who know nothing about tuning just throw it in there, close their code and call it a day. The problem with this is that you still have to limit yourself to a finite set of pitches that you have to decide *before* you compose. None of the software I've found that supports Scala offers any way to automatically update the loaded scale. Clickety-clickety-click, you'll be clicking away. It didn't have to be this way.
MTS not only offers per-note tuning for 128 notes, but any of them can be changed *on the fly*. Scala is great for playing. For complete tuning freedom, it isn't that useful.
I've seen instruments in Csound and Pure Data that had a perfect system: same standard MIDI note numbers, but with decimals. If you want 60, like most musicians, you put in 60 and get out middle C. If you want 17 cents up from middle C, you tell it 60.17. Seems obvious, and this would be a cinch to implement in almost all existing MIDI software, but you have to actually know something about tuning to realize that it would be better.
64-bit audio samples are already standard in commercial DAWs. Why do they still force 7 bits of pitch precision?